# Passing parameters only working for html not for .ts

Tags: angular

currently im trying to subscribe to a special parameter like this.

```html
public zType = [] as any;
constructor (private zService: ZuordnungService)


this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this.zService
      .getTypeId(id)
      .subscribe(data =>  { this.zType = data; })
       
    });
    console.log(this.zType.personentypId)
```

The console log gives me "Undefined" but i tried it also via html:

```html
 <div id="supporter">
                Supporter: {{zType.personentypId}}
            </div>
```

And it shows me the correct id? Why does the console.log says its undefined and html tells me its possible and the correct id.

Comment: Perhaps the callback in `subscribe` hasn't been invoked yet when `console.log` executes? You may try adding another log inside the callback and see the order of execution: `.subscribe(data =>  { console.log(data); this.zType = data; })`

Comment: thx for the answer but still undefined.

Comment: Learn about RxJs and async code. `subscribe` completes immediately.

Comment: Thx thats helpful! I will read about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. public zType = [] as any;
2. this.route.params.subscribe(params => {

   });
3. console.log(this.zType.personentypId)

Callback within `subscribe` method is executing asynchronously.
Since, you have used data type any for `zType` console is printing 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this code will fix your problem as there's not enough information here, e.g. We don't know what `this.zService.getTypeId(id)` returns, etc., but you should rewrite your code as follows:

```
public zType = this.route.params.pipe(
    switchMap(({ id }) => this.zService.getTypeId(id)
); // now returns an observable of the type getTypeId returns

constructor (private zService: ZuordnungService)
```

```
// uses async pipe to subscribe to changes in zType and display the personetypId
 <div id="supporter">
      Supporter: {{ (zType | async)?.personentypId }}
 </div>
```